# Why downloaded file is bigger than input stream?

Tags: c#, stream, download

I'm writing a C# method to get a MemoryStream and download it as file in browser.
I load a .xlsx file using FileStream and copy it to MemoryStream

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    docStream = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(docStream);
}
```

Then I pass the docStream to OpenXML class

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docStream, true))
```

and update the content using OpenXML classes and methods.
Finally I pass the docStream to DownloadStream method but, the downloaded file is larger than size of the stream.

```
public class Utility
{
    public static void DownloadStream(MemoryStream inputStream, string filename)
    {
        byte[] bytes = inputStream.ToArray();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
}
```

I put a break-point and verified the `inputStream.Lentgh` is `17112` bytes.
I also confirmed that `bytes.Length` is `17112`.

When I check the download file (which is an .xslx), it's size is `25983` bytes.

Also when I open the file, I get a warning that file may corrupt but Excel is is able to repair it.

Comment: Well your stream is one encoding and the file is in another obviously.

Comment: Interesting point! How can I check what is the stream encoding and what it should be?

Comment: `StreamReader` has the property `CurrentEncording` but it tends to be wrong. I don't remember how exactly but there is a way you can simply check the BOM which are the first 4 bytes. [Here's the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of BOM for each encoding. It may not be your problem but byte count changes smells like encoding difference big time.

Comment: I don't use StreamReader because the file is binary. I added more detail if you are interested to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by finding similar problem in SO. It was not related to Encoding.

The problem was I needed to add:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

to my DownloadStream method after `BinaryWrite`.

```
public static void DownloadStream(MemoryStream inputStream, string filename)
{
    byte[] bytes = inputStream.ToArray();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); // This is the key
}
```